# Scheduling executions in retaliation to terrorist acts

Tags: terrorism, human-rights

According to [news reports](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/islamic-state/11381114/Jordan-threatens-to-fast-track-execution-of-its-Isil-prisoners-if-pilot-not-freed.html), Jordan is threatening to hasten the execution of terrorists in retaliation if daesh kills Jordanian hostage Moaz al-Kaseasbeh. That is, Jordan's treating its own prisoners as hostages in some respects.

Apart from the application of the death penalty, and potential issues relating to the fairness of trials, are there any theoretical human rights that could be violated as a result of this action?  For example, would it be seen as collective punishment?  This was answered on [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/1902/100) for the current legal rights.

Comment: It wouldn't be collective punishment (it's punishing terrorists, not a whole population), but this question is kind of broad and arguably off-topic. We can hardly review all international law here.

Comment: Sound like conventions dealing with prisoner treatment (appropriate pieces of Geneva C) may be violated here. The question is, are those terrorists prisoners of war?

Comment: @DVK I suspect terrorists sometimes like to see themselves as POWs. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blanket_protest

Comment: Answered on law.SE: http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1902/hastening-execution-in-response-to-actions-by-third-parties

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been answered on law.SE: http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1902/hastening-execution-in-response-to-actions-by-third-parties

Comment: Apparently an answer exists at: http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1902/hastening-execution-in-response-to-actions-by-third-parties